# MySQL Charset Fails When DateTime Column on WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have a MYSQL query like below:

```
SELECT YA.PROGRAMNAME
FROM    TABLE_Y YA
WHERE   YA.PROGRAMID=9845 
AND YA.ENDDATE>NOW()
```

When executed, this query doesn't correctly return the language specific characters (here, Turkish characters)
Above query outputs:

```
Zaman?n Tan???
```

Turkish characters are replaced with question marks.

If I omit the last line of the query, then it works correctly but I miss to control if the program's end date is greater than now.

```
SELECT YA.PROGRAMNAME
FROM    TABLE_Y YA
WHERE   YA.PROGRAMID=9845

/* Outputs: Zamanın Tanığı */
```

On a side note: the charset for TABLE_Y is latin5.

What can I do to have it working correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I've sent a bug report to MySQL, as seen on [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62068)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange behavior with WHERE clause.

I'd suggest you to configure session before selecting, e.g. -

```
SET NAMES latin5; -- or SET NAMES utf8;
SELECT YA.PROGRAMNAME
FROM    TABLE_Y YA
...
```

### **EDIT**

Cannot reproduce the problem. There may be a problem on the client, but I'm not sure.

```
CREATE TABLE table_y(
  PROGRAMID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PROGRAMNAME VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ENDDATE DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PROGRAMID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
CHARACTER SET latin5
COLLATE latin5_turkish_ci;

INSERT INTO table_y VALUES 
  (1, 'Zamanın Tanığı', '2014-10-03'),
  (2, 'Zamanın Tanığı', '2011-06-03');

SET NAMES latin1;
SELECT YA.PROGRAMNAME FROM TABLE_Y YA WHERE YA.PROGRAMID = 1 AND YA.ENDDATE > NOW();
---------------------------
Zaman?n Tan???


SET NAMES latin5;
SELECT YA.PROGRAMNAME FROM TABLE_Y YA WHERE YA.PROGRAMID = 1 AND YA.ENDDATE > NOW();
---------------------------
Zamanın Tanığı
```

Comment: It seems the data itself in my database is corrupt which has an enddate greater than 10th april. Thus you cannot reproduce it... Sorry for the wrong alarm, but thanks again, you helped me on this.